# How to use Codeception to test laravel 5 APIs?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, codeception

I am new to Codeception and I am trying to test my web service which I have built using Laravel 5. I am following the guide [here](http://codeception.com/docs/10-WebServices).

So I created a suite called api first:

```
codecept generate:suite api
```

**api.suite.yml**

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            url: http://localhost:8000/api/
            depends: Laravel5
```

**AuthenticateUserCept.php**

```
<?php 
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('authenticate a user');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$I->sendPOST('/authenticate', [
    'username' => 'archive',
    'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
    'password' => 'password'
]);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
```

I have already tried this using Postman and it runs fine. The `/authenticate` route takes the 3 parameters and spits out a JWT token happily but I cannot make it work with Codeception.

```
1) Failed to authenticate a user in AuthenticateUserCept (tests/api//AuthenticateUserCept.php)

 Step  I see response code is 200
 Fail  Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.

Scenario Steps:

 3. $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200)
 2. $I->sendPOST("/authenticate",{"username":"archive","email":"admin@admin.com","password":"password"})
 1. $I->haveHttpHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Where am I going wrong? And moreover it is still blurry to me that how do I refactor this particular test in order to have a JWT for other requests that I make. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT changes in api.suite.yml**

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            url: http://localhost:8000/api/
            depends: Laravel5
    config: 
        Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer, some comments:

- on the enabled line in api.suite.yml I include: enabled: [PhpBrowser, REST, ApiHelper, Asserts].
- The url in the REST line doesn't make any difference for the API suite, it's usually only used for the acceptance suite. This should be doing everything via the routes directly into your code instead of using phpbrowser mode or similar where it's making HTTP calls.
- Instead of using the PhpBrowser mode you can use the Laravel5 mode -- the former will send requests through the middleware, the Laravel5 mode won't put requests through the middleware if the APP_ENV is set to testing.

In terms of how to fix this, I would start by trying to figure out what the code is doing to spit out the 500 error.  One thing that you might do is try to insert some debug/log lines in your code. Another thing is to put in a line like this into the test case:

$I->seeResponseContains('blablabla');

Of course that will fail, but it will produce an output in the tests/_output directory so that you can see exactly what response your code gave back along with the 500 error (of course you need to do this the step before testing for the 200 condition, otherwise your test will bail out at that step).

One common cause of this type of error in test cases is validation applied to a custom Request class that's passed in to your controller method. If that validation fails then the controller method doesn't get hit and you will get a 500 error without being able to debug it in the controller. I consider custom Request classes of this type to be a bad idea.

Another possible line of enquiry is to build a functional test that tests the same route. Functional tests via the Laravel5 helper module are usually easier to get working and get debugged. Once you have a basic functional test in place and resolve any problems that you hit getting that going then it's easier to get the API tests working.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful insight. So I went ahead and changed the POST request to `/api/authenticate` this time. So I dug in to the output of the test. And I figured out a middle ware which checks tokens to evaluate the payload is messing this up but that middleware is not supposed to act on `/api/authenticate` out of obvious reasons. But when I comment the middleware from the Kernal, it runs fine. How do I go around this?

Comment: Put this into your api.suite.yml:

    config:
        Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing

In your file .env.testing, ensure that you have set:

APP_ENV=testing

Otherwise it should be the same as your .env file.

By default when APP_ENV=testing the middleware doesn't get run.  You can re-enable it on a case by case basis but that should solve your issue.

Comment: I am not sure I got the whole thing. I changed the config file, I'll even edit my answer to include the changes. I created the .env.testing and set the `APP_ENV` to testing. But I don't get what you mean about the middleware. The test still fails. The middleware which tries to parse a token which it shouldn't. Once I comment the middleware in the Kernal, it passes, but that's not how I wish to tackle this. The middleware looks if the request is `api/authenticate` and it skips then. Maybe codeception is not performing HTTP request? It does it in another. I am confused.

Comment: I changed Laravel5 to PhpBrowser in the REST dependencies. Laravel5 module was not simulating real HTTP requests and which is why the middleware was not running correctly. PhpBrowser simulates real HTTP requests apparently. Kindly updated the answer with this information too and I will accept it. Thank you for the other information though. :)

Comment: OK noted -- in some cases the Laravel5 module is preferable if you don't want middleware on by default. You can always enable or disable middleware specifically for any given test.